# Нужна помощь с MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm

Доброго времени суток.
Спустя долго время решил опробовать модель MVVM. Сразу же возникли трудности.

Решил начать с таймера, который каждую секунду передает значение в Label.

Как положено создал 3 папки

- Models
  Timers.cs
- Viewmodels
  MainWindowViewModel.cs
- Views
  MainWindow.xaml

  ```
  public class Timers : INotifyPropertyChanged 
  {
     DispatcherTimer _flwpTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

     public  string _fullTimeProgrammWork;

     public string FullTimeProgrammWork
     {
          get { return _fullTimeProgrammWork; }
          set { _fullTimeProgrammWork = value;
              OnPropertyChanged("FullTimeProgrammWork");
          }
     }

      void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
      {
          if (PropertyChanged != null)
              PropertyChanged(this, new 
          PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      private string Int2StringTime(int time, int addtime)
      {
          time = Properties.Settings.Default.ProgrammWorkTimeInt;
          time += addtime;
          int hours = (time - (time % (60 * 60))) / (60 * 60);
          int minutes = (time - time % 60) / 60 - hours * 60;
          int seconds = time - hours * 60 * 60 - minutes * 60;
          return String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", hours, minutes, seconds);
      }

      public void TimerStart()
      {
          _flwpTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(timerTick);
          _flwpTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1000);
          _flwpTimer.Start();
      }
      private void timerStop()
      {
          _flwpTimer.Stop();
          _flwpTimer.IsEnabled = false;
      }
      public void timerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          Properties.Settings.Default.ProgrammWorkTimeString = Int2StringTime(Properties.Settings.Default.ProgrammWorkTimeInt, 1);
          Properties.Settings.Default.ProgrammWorkTimeInt++;
          Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
          SetFullTime();
      }

  }
  ```

  }

В xaml указал

```
 xmlns:md="clr-namespace:PersonalTrainer.ViewModels"
```

и

```
<Window.DataContext>
     <md:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

и соответственно сам Label

```
 <Label x:Name="fullTimeProgrammWorkLabel" Content="{Binding Path=FullTimeProgrammWork}"  Margin="10,80,10,286" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="20"   />
```

По модели передачу данных нужно реализовать в

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
    {

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {     
        }

    }
```

Не могу понять как реализовать передачу каждую секунду

Comment: На каждый тик таймера вы должны изменять значение свойства `FullTimeProgrammWork`, которое у вас связано с `Label`. А у вас вместо этого записываются новые значения времени в `Properties.Settings.Default.ProgrammWorkTimeString`?! Передавайте значения в свойство, тогда и увидите изменения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код какой-то неполный, так что не уверен во всем что пишу. Но смотрите. Заведите этот класс как `публичное свойство` (это важно!) в `MainWindowViewModel`

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public Timers Timer {get;set;}

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {     
        Timer = new Timers(); //тут стартаните его или что надо сделайте
    }
 }
```

Ну и привязывайтесь к нему (Надеюсь вы обновляете `FullTimeProgrammWork` в ф-ции `SetFullTime();` - если нет - обновляйте где-нибудь!):

```
<Label  Content="{Binding Timer.FullTimeProgrammWork}"  />
```

Должно сработать.
Это вариант с минимальными изменениями вашего кода, есть еще несколько способов как сделать. Вплоть до использования мессанджеров (например из какого-нибудь `MVVM` фреймворка). Я бы вообще в `MainWindowViewModel` все это замутил, не вынося в класс - хранил бы просто время как у вас в `int` (?) (к которому бы и привязывался), а для отображения написал бы конвертер (ведь `ViewModel` не должна заботится о способе отображения своих данных). Как-то так.

Answer (score 0):

Была путаница в классах и в том что не задавал начальное значение при старте программы. 
Сейчас выглядит это так

- Models

MainWindowModel.cs

- ViewModels

ViewModel.cs

- Views

MainWindow.xaml

```
class MainWindowModel : ViewModels.ViewModel
    {
        public MainWindowModel()
        {
        }

        public string _fullTimeProgrammWork = Properties.Settings.Default.ProgrammWorkTimeString;
        public string FullTimeProgrammWork
        {
            get => _fullTimeProgrammWork;
            set => Set(ref _fullTimeProgrammWork, value);
        }
}




abstract class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }


        protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string Property = null)
        {
            if (Equals(field, value)) return false;
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(Property);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
     xmlns:md="clr-namespace:PersonalTrainer.Models"
    <Window.DataContext>
        <md:MainWindowModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
  <Label x:Name="fullTimeProgrammWorkLabel" Content="{Binding FullTimeProgrammWork, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   />
```